# UnicodeDecodeError when using json.dumps

Tags: python, json, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to return a json object with special characters.
The line that crashes is:

```
return json.dumps([x.toDict() for x in searches], ensure_ascii=False)
```

The toDict function:

```
def toDict(self):
  """Expect to dico. Needed before serialization in JSON"""
  out = {}
  if self.wkid is not None:
    out['wkid'] = self.wkid
  if self.wkt is not None:
    out['wkt'] = self.wkt
  return(out)
```

When I print *x* in `for x in searches`:

```
for x in searches:
  print x.toDict()

{'crs': {'wkid': 4326, 'wkt': 'WGS84'}, 'candidates': [{'score': 200, 'type': 'ADR', 'location': {'y': 50.2485465358886, 'x': 4.38243469412172, 'crs': {'wkid': 4326, 'wkt': 'WGS84'}}, 'address': {'city': 'Fontenelle', 'munkey': '0585'}}, {'score': 200, 'type': 'ADR', 'location': {'y': 50.4123146893214, 'x': 4.32436581556278, 'crs': {'wkid': 4326, 'wkt': 'WGS84'}}, 'address': {'city': "Fontaine-l'\\xe3\\x89v\\xe3\\xaaque", 'munkey': '0324'}}, {'score': 200, 'type': 'ADR', 'location': {'y': 50.3217667573625, 'x': 4.21386030471998, 'crs': {'wkid': 4326, 'wkt': 'WGS84'}}, 'address': {'city': 'Fontaine-valmont', 'munkey': '0362'}}, {'score': 200, 'type': 'ADR', 'location': {'y': 49.7151404477129, 'x': 5.23438436377951, 'crs': {'wkid': 4326, 'wkt': 'WGS84'}}, 'address': {'city': 'Fontenoille', 'munkey': '0541'}}], 'id': u'1', 'address': {'city': u'Fontaine-lev', 'street': u'Avenue des Chones', 'zone': u'1301', 'house': u'19'}}
```

This works fine. However, when I try:

```
for x in searches:
  print json.dumps(x.toDict(), ensure_ascii=False)
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError('ascii', '"Fontaine-l\\'\\xe3\\x89v\\xe3\\xaaque"', 12, 13, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128).
```

Strange, considering that I pass ensure_ascii=False to specify that the text should not be decoded..

What could be wrong that it is still trying to decode the text?

Comment: This string is being fetched from a PostGreSQL DB. I've edited my OP to include the full object, printing it as is works fine, but using json.dumps(object, ensure_ascii=False) still crashes with the unicode error. I will look into the wrong encoding, but I'm still a bit confused why it crashes even when specifying that it should be returned as is without decoding..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ensure_ascii=False` doesn't mean it will not decode the unicode literals.

> If ensure_ascii is false, some chunks written to fp may be unicode instances. This usually happens because the input contains unicode strings or the encoding parameter is used. **Unless fp.write() explicitly understands unicode (as in codecs.getwriter()) this is likely to cause an error.**

from [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I'll have to take a look at exactly how this string was encoded in the DB, and how I should correctly decode it.